# Отправка .xls-файла в сервлете

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

На JSP я отправляю *.xls*-файл по запросу пользователя. Хочу так же сделать в сервлете:

```
out.clear();
out = pageContext.pushBody();
response.setHeader("Content-type","application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=AirAstana - Sessions.xls");
wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

Но в сервлете нет `pageContext` и `out.clear()` - есть только `out.close()` и `out.flush()`.

Как можно в сервлете отправить файл?

Answer (score 1):

А так?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    resp.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\"AirAstana - Sessions.xls\"");
}
```

Comment: да так делал и дописывал wb.write(response.getOutputStream()); но она записывает в xsl то что должно выводится в out, если было out.print(1) она записывает в xsl файл 1.

Comment: @JTan см. [Create an excel file for users to download using Apache POI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226603/create-an-excel-file-for-users-to-download-using-apache-poi)